Better alternative to iterrows() when needing to set dynamic date range in a for loop in Python?
Hoping that the title makes some sense. I'm essentially trying to pull data via the GA4 Reporting API in Python, but since this API has a 10k rows limit, I need to select smaller time ranges (1 month at a time versus a 12 months, for example) and concatenate the resulting 1 month dataframe together to create the final dataset.
Currently the (probably inappropriate) solution I've found is to create a dataframe with 2 columns, "starting_date" and "ending_date". I then built the API request to loop over each row of this dataframe to fetch the starting_date and ending_date of the API request (always 1 month's worth of time) dynamically, and append the result of each loop to a new dataframe which I can use.
I keep reading that iterating through dataframes is a big nono. It works, but as time goes on I feel like it may get slower and slower. What's the best alternative to achieve what I'm trying to do more efficiently?
Here's the code example:
#Create the date range dataframe
def create_date_dataframe(start_date='2022-11-01'):
    start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    end_date = datetime.now()
    date_range = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='MS')
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'starting_date': date_range,
        'ending_date': date_range + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)
    })
    return df 
date_df = create_date_dataframe().reset_index()

#Start the API request function
pre_final_data= pd.DataFrame()
final_data = pd.DataFrame()

def core_kpi_pipeline():
    global pre_final_data, final_data
    for index, row in date_df.iterrows():
        property_id = "#########"
        starting_date = row['starting_date'].strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        ending_date = row['ending_date'].strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
#etc....


couldn't you do a request for the month, get a dataframe for the month, put all the months in a list, and then do a pd.concat([[month-1, month-2...month-n]], axis=0)?

an alternative to using iterrows() would be to use the apply function. I would need sample data (input and output) of exactly what you are trying to accomplish to give you an answer

@iBeMeltin I think I may try that. Idea would essentially be to build the function and then use the apply method on the function such that it would run once per row of the dataframe, correct? This just might work.

essentially yes
